# Create GO like AI - maybe with minimax algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

So I'm trying to make a game that's similar to the game GO. Essentially I've got a grid of faces, and when you click on a face they turn your respective color (red and blue). You and your opponent take turns clicking on faces to color them your respective color. When any amount of faces are surrounded by faces that are of all the same color, then all the faces that are surrounded are deleted from the board, and the number deleted is added as score to the player whose color surrounded. And if you tap a face twice with the same color (so red face is tapped by red again) then it bursts leaving residue around that face's surrounding faces making it so those residued faces can't have their color change to the other color that's not the residue color.Now my hope is that I could get a slightly working AI, it doesn't have to be amazing or anything, just good enough to make decently intelligent moves and could possibly win. After doing some research it seems that using a MiniMax algorithm would be my best bet, but I have no clue how to create such a thing in unity. I was hoping someone might have some insight on how to accomplish this, or does anyone have a better idea of an algorithm that would be better in determining moves?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is horribly broad question, however - one of the most succesful approaches to the board games AI (especially GO) is UCT based approach. It is a monte carlo driven heuristic approximation of the minmax algorithm. MinMax requires game's state space to be very small in order to fit in both memory and time constraints. UCT on the other hand can make reasonable moves in any given amount of time (it is fully iterative).